# Is connecting to my SQL server by IP on the server computer different to other computers for testing purposes?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a VB.NET application that utilises databases in an SQL server. I am currently testing the application on the same computer the server is hosted on.

I connect to the server through the following connection string...

```
("Data Source = " & Master.CurrentIP.Text & ",1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=ExcelDM;User ID=" & Master.CurrentUser.Text & ";Password=" & Master.CurrentPass.Text & ";")
```

"Master.CurrentIP.Text" refers to my public IP address and not my computer's.

Basically, everything works perfectly when I test the application on this computer. I am wondering if I can use this as a test for other computers joining or not. Should I host my server on something that isn't my computer?

To clarify, remote connections is enabled on the server and port forwarding (port # 1433) is open both incoming and outgoing through windows firewall and my router port forwarding settings. All TCP/IP options are open in the SQL configuration manager etc.

Comment: You can host your SQL server wherever you want for testing - on your machine is fine. I assume when going to production the app will be connecting across a LAN, and not over WAN? Either way, the connection protocol is better off in a configuration file (not the user/password, ideally you should use Windows security if on a domain or some other auth method if not) rather than hard coded into the app, that way you can support a lot more configurations of SQL server in case you need to secure it in a way that you didn't account for in the first place.

Comment: Are you basically asking if everyone on the Internet can use your public IP address to interact with your database? Do you understand what security concerns this scenario raises?

Comment: @Steve, this is an App I am designing for personal use with friends. It is an SQL-hosted multi-user environment for designing Dungeons and Dragons campaigns. I only want to know if it is a waste of time testing SQL-connectivity through IP when server and Application are in the same environment. Thankyou for your questions.

Comment: @Charleh, there are a lot of good touching points in your answer! This is first time I have done anything like this. WAN versus LAN; config file; windows security. I will do some googling based on these keywords, many thanks!

Comment: @Charleh, the app will be used by a small group of people all over the world. So I will not be using LAN. Is WAN preferable? And how does this concern my code; the network library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'd make the following assumptions:

- You aren't holding any sensitive data, so security isn't a major concern
- You are going to be running this on a LAN (local area network) and not over the web

If that's the case I'd suggest the following:

- You are fine testing on your local machine - the connection will work the same over any protocol on local or remote, and given the small amount of data in a D&D campaign, you probably aren't going to be worried about performance even if your application is very chatty with SQL server
- Put your connection information in the application configuration file, this is supported in .NET framework with some helper types like `ConfigurationManager` where you can access connection strings like so:

Config file:

```
 <connectionStrings>  
   <add name="MyConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=somehostname;database=Dungeons;uid=user;password=password" />  
 </connectionStrings>
```

c# code

```
 string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"];
```

See here for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

- Since your friends probably don't want to mess with your SQL server and you are probably not joined to a windows domain, I'd say you are fine with putting secrets (user/pass) in the connection string in the configuration file
- I'd not bother with what I said about Windows security - basically the users on the client machines would be used as credentials to the SQL database, this would be a bit more of a headache to configure if you aren't all joined to a domain rather than just embedding a SQL user/pass in the config

** Edit: **

Further to conversation, if you are writing an app that clients will be accessing over the web, using a direct SQL connection is not usually the best idea, but it can work if you can manage your clients/IPs.

Generally, opening your SQL server up to the internet is just asking to be attacked - and unless your SQL server is up to date, this can lead to the host machine being compromised.

At best it's an inconvenience, but if you are using that machine for anything other than D&D data, then you probably don't want someone snooping around on it.

**In the case that you don't want to change your application architecture**

You can whitelist your clients in SQL server/on the firewall. Since it's only friends (let's say 10-20 people?), you can manage their IPs without too much trouble.

This prevents the general internet from being able to access your server.

You could also use a VPN (either software or on your hardware if your router supports it). This also has the effect of putting your clients on your LAN essentially, removing the need for any firewall config apart from the VPN itself.

**In the case you are interested in changing your app architecture**

You can use a service based approach. This is what is generally used to secure web-based services - .NET framework supports this with WCF (Windows Communication Foundation).

This allows you to define service contracts that your server/client can adhere to.

The communication protocol/method itself is decided via configuration, so you can change what mechanism is used to communicate between client/server after-the-fact without having to change your application code.

This does require you to write a service layer though - you won't be able to directly access SQL from your client, but it could be a useful learning experience, especially if you are interested in doing work like this in the future.

Read about WCF here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf

There's also the REST based approach which sits down at the HTTP level, .NET framework can support this via ASP.NET web API.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis

... so in short, there are a few options

Comment: thankyou for the response! I am currently working through the information you have given me; however there is one thing. I will be using this application over the web with other Dungeon Masters, and not over LAN. Does this change things considerably? As in, we will not be in the same geographical location or on the same internet conection.

Comment: Yes and no - if you really want to do this, you have to carefully consider how you give access to your SQL server. If you open ports and leave SQL listening, there's a chance someone is going to port scan and probe for vulnerabilities. In this case, whitelisting clients by IP is a good idea (Azure SQL, the cloud based solution essentially does this). Without changing your app to use a service based approach you don't have many other options. A service based approach basically shields access to your SQL server by putting your API on the web and not your whole server. Is whitelisting an option?

Comment: I hear your concerns about security. This project is a way for me to learn about all of these concepts and put them into practice over the course of this year. Whitelisting seems like it will be necessary at a point where the app is fully operational. For now I am just trying to get to a stage where I can open the app on another computer and have it work 100% like it does on mine.

Comment: Well, you should already be there on your LAN then, and it *will* work over WAN without too much trouble (firewall etc). Just be careful out there :)

Comment: Note: you can also use a VPN where your clients can dial onto your network as if they are on LAN. I'm not sure how difficult this is to setup on a home machine (not sure how many software VPNs are out there) but certainly if your network kit (i.e. router) supports VPNs you can use that. That would essentially remove the risks since your clients would be **on** your LAN.